# Simply reverting changes from a commit

Tags: git, git-revert

Say I have a file that has been added to over time and committed into Git each time. How does one simply revert one of the earlier commits but retain the all the following commits?

For example, a blank `file.txt` is added and committed. Each subsequent commit adds an increasing number. I wish to simply undo the first number added (1) but retain the others (2 & 3). It seems like I should use `revert` but I'm a little lost.

```
➜ ls
file.txt

➜ cat file.txt
1
2
3

➜ git log --oneline
afc6136 Add 3
d0cbec0 Add 2
1d6a4ff Add 1
b6c3a92 Init file.txt

➜ git revert 1d6a4ff
error: could not revert 1d6a4ff... Add 1
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

➜ cat file.txt
<<<<<<< HEAD
1
2
3
=======
>>>>>>> parent of 1d6a4ff... Add 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news: you're on the right track!

However, since all your changes were very close to eachother, you get a conflict. In essence, git is saying "too much has changed around here since the commit we're reverting, and I don't feel comfortable guessing -- please tidy things up and tell me when you're done".

Each conflicted chunk is marked as such:

```
<<<<<<< some commit
(chunk's content in some commit)
=======
(chunk's content in some other commit)
>>>>>>> some other commit
```

You should edit the chunk to look like you want it, remove the separators (the "<<<", "===", and ">>>" lines), then `git add` the file and `git commit` it (as suggested by the message git threw you).

In your case, the whole file is inside the chunk -- that's not always the case. Try with a bigger base file (as in "more lines") in your initial commit, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean there are too many changes within a specific location or time?

Comment: Location. If your changes were more spread out in the file (more lines between your additions), you wouldn't get a conflict.